# Find $a_n$ such that the formula is equal to $\zeta(2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, integers, pi, constants

My question start with the observation :

$$\sqrt{e}\simeq \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

At first glance it's not really convincing but after some work I found :

$$\sqrt{e-5\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{2}+2\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{3}+9\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{4}-4\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{5}}\simeq \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Wich is really better .

So now my question is clear :

If we have :

$$\sqrt{e-5\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{2}+2\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{3}+9\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{4}-4\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{5}+\cdots+a_n\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{n}+\cdots}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Where $a_n\in Z$

How to find $a_n$ ?

I don't find it in the librairy of integer .On the other hand it seems a bit artificial anyway perhaps there is some interest but I ignore it currently .

Thanks for your help .

Side notes :

$$\sqrt{e}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}k!}$$

We have also :

$\lim_{a\to \infty}\exp\left(\frac{a}{a+\frac{a}{\exp\left(a-\frac{a}{\exp\left(a\frac{a}{\exp\left(a+\frac{a}{\exp\left(a-\frac{a}{\exp\left(a-a\cdot\frac{a}{\exp\left(a...\right)}\right)}\right)}\right)}\right)}\right)}}\right)=e^{\frac{1}{2}}$

And see the wiki page about the Vieta's formula for $\pi$

Comment: So we can rewrite this: $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e})^i=\frac{{\pi}^4}{36}-e$. I think that there will be more than one set of $a_n$-s to get the same accuracy. May be you can ask about the minimal average coefficient value.

Comment: Just to clarify : You are interested in a description of a complete sequence $a_n$ such that we have equality ? I do not think that this is possible !

Comment: @Peter interesting comment what is your argument ?I'm interested only on one sequence not all .

Comment: @Peter for example $$-3*10^{-15}<\sqrt{e-5\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{2}+2\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{3}+9\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{4}-4\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{5}+2\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{6}+9\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{7}+11\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{8}-25\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{9}-10\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{10}}-\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}<-1*10^{-15}$$

Comment: But you are interested in an exact value and a description of some sequence $a_n$ , right ? I am pretty sure that such a sequence exists, but completely describing it is something else.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gevorg Hmayakyan says, the problem can be rephased as finding a sequence $a_n\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that

\begin{equation}
     \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i \left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{i}=\frac{\pi^4}{36}-e
\end{equation}

To to this, I use a greedy algorithm, i.e., in each step the error is maximally reduced. Therefore, $a_{n+1}=\mathrm{nint}(\tilde{a}_{n+1})$, where $\mathrm{nint}(\cdot)$ denotes the nearest integer,

\begin{equation}
    \tilde{a}_{n+1}:= \frac{\frac{\pi^4}{36}-e-\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{i}}{\left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{n+1}}
\end{equation}

and $a_0=0$.

Now, we prove that the series converges. Note that, $|a_n-\tilde{a}_n|\leq \frac{1}{2}$, which implies that

\begin{equation}
     \left| \left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e} \right)^n \tilde{a}_n - \left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^n a_n \right| \leq \frac{1}{2} \left|\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right|^{n}
\end{equation}

Using the definition of $\tilde{a}_n$,

\begin{equation}
     \left| \frac{\pi^4}{36} - e - \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^i a_i \right| \leq \frac{1}{2} \left|\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right|^{n}
\end{equation}

Since $\left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{\pi}\right) \approx 0.0496<1$, the series converges to $\frac{\pi^4}{36}- e$. Interestingly, note that $|\tilde{a}_n|\leq\frac{e \cdot \pi}{2(e-\pi)}\approx 10.08$, therefore, $|a_n|\leq 10$. Finally, any sequence $b_n$,

\begin{equation}
       b_{n+1}=\mathrm{nint}\left(\frac{h_n-\sum_{i=0}^n b_i g_n^i}{g_n^{n+1}}\right)
\end{equation}

where $b_0=0$, $h_n\rightarrow \frac{\pi^4}{36}-e$, and $g_n\rightarrow \frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, satisfies

\begin{equation}
      \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_n \left(\frac{1}{\pi}- \frac{1}{e} \right)^i = \frac{\pi^4}{36}-e
\end{equation}

This follows since, $|h_n-\frac{\pi^4}{36}+e|\leq E_n$, where $E_n \rightarrow 0$, and

\begin{equation}
     \left|h_{n-1}-\sum_{i=1}^n g_n^i b_i\right| \leq \frac{g_n^n}{2}
\end{equation}

Therefore, $ \left|\frac{\pi^4}{36}-e-\sum_{i=1}^n g_n^i b_i\right|\leq \frac{g_n^n}{2}+ E_n$. Now, using that $g_n=\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}+\epsilon_n$, where $\epsilon_n\rightarrow 0$,

\begin{align}
    \left|\frac{\pi^4}{36}-e-\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{\pi}-\frac{1}{e}\right)^i b_i\right|&\leq \frac{g_n^n}{2}+ E_n+ \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \binom{i}{j} \left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{\pi}\right)^j \epsilon_n^{i-j}\\ & =\frac{g_n^n}{2}+ E_n+ \epsilon_n \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \binom{i}{j} \left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{\pi}\right)^j \epsilon_n^{i-j-1} \\& \leq \frac{g_n^n}{2}+ E_n+ \epsilon_n \left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{\pi}\right)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \left[2\left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{\pi}\right)\right]^i \\ & \leq \frac{g_n^n}{2}+ E_n+ \epsilon_n \frac{2}{1-2\left(\frac{1}{e}-\frac{1}{\pi}\right)}
\end{align}

For example

\begin{equation}
       h_n= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{5}{2i^4}-\frac{1}{i!}\right) -1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
       g_n= \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9801} \frac{(4i)!(1103+26390i)}{(i!)^4 396^{4i}}- \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}
\end{equation}

Comment: let me have a look...(+1) for the effort !

Comment: $${\frac {1}{\pi }}={\frac {2{\sqrt {2}}}{9801}}\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {(4k)!(1103+26390k)}{(k!)^{4}396^{4k}}}$$ You should had the link refering to Ramanujan for this formula

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the link. By the way, I've been thinking about some sequence that wasn't like $b_n$, but the truth is that I can't think of anything.

Comment: This is a very nice work ! I was thinking about integer progamming under constraints but is is awwful. Cheers & ***Happy New Year !***